# google sheet API, Deleting row

Tags: typescript, google-api

so i am trying to do a simple task which is deleting rows in my google sheet. surprisingly, it isn't work like I expected.
so from the code below, you could see I am entering all the row number i would like to delete & i wrote down console log to make sure these are the rows I want them to be deleted

```
 for(let i = 0; i < deletion.length; i++)
 {
            console.log("deleteing " + rowCharacter[deletion[i]].Discord)
            await rowCharacter[deletion[i]].delete()
            console.log("deleteing " + rowCharacter[deletion[i]].Discord)    
 }
```

Some of the rows end up deleted. Some will not.
Any suggestions will be much appreciated or even one command that could clear everything without doing a loop? I will share the entirety of the method below:

```
async cleanSheet(discordtag:string[]){
        await this.memo.loadCells()
        let begin = this.memo.rowCount
        let rowCharacter = await this.character.getRows()
        let deletion:number[] = [], i = 415 , row:GoogleSpreadsheetRow[] = []
        console.log("start")
        for(let j = 0;  i < rowCharacter.length; j++)
        {
            console.log("checking" + rowCharacter[i].Discord)
            if(rowCharacter[i]?.Discord == undefined)
            {
                    i++
            }
            //console.log( rowCharacter[i].Discord)
            else if(discordtag[j] == rowCharacter[i].Discord)
            {
                i++
                j = 0
            }
            else if(j == discordtag.length)
            {
                console.log(rowCharacter[i].Discord)
                rowCharacter[i].Character = rowCharacter[i].Character + " [retired]"
                console.log("rows to add" +rowCharacter[i].Character)

                row.push(rowCharacter[i])
                //await this.memo.addRow(rowCharacter[i])
                deletion.push(i)
                i++
                j = 0
            }
        }
        await this.memo.addRows(row)
        console.log("rows to delete" + deletion)
        let end = deletion.length + begin
        for(let i = 0; i < deletion.length; i++)
        {
            console.log("deleteing " + rowCharacter[deletion[i]].Discord)
            
            await rowCharacter[deletion[i]].delete()
            console.log("deleteing " + rowCharacter[deletion[i]].Discord)

        }
        await this.memo.loadCells()
    
        for(let i = begin; i < end; i++)
            for( let j = 0; j < 49; j++)
                this.memo.getCell(i,j).borders = this.memo.getCell(1,1).borders
        
        this.memo.saveUpdatedCells()
        console.log("done")

    }
```

Comment: to delete rows, be careful to start from the end (reverse your loop), otherwise the index of the row would be affected by the previous deletion.

Answer (score 0):

```
to delete rows, be careful to start from the end (reverse your loop), otherwise the index of the row would be affected by the previous deletion. – 
Mike Steelson
```

Mike Steelson thank you for ur answer. You were right.